# Last expandable cardview of Recyclerview needs scrolling

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-cardview, expandable

my question is actually exactly the same as this one: [RecyclerView expandable cardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686856/recyclerview-expandable-cardview) but no good solution was given, that's why I'm asking this question again.
So the problem is that when I click the last cardView, it expands but the expandable part isn't visible, I have to scroll down to see it. I tried `scrollToPosition` but that didn't work.
Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!