# RecyclerView does not auto scroll to expanded ViewHolder item

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView containing my list of ViewHolder items.  When a user touches an item, its layout/view expands to show more details.  Pretty standard stuff and works great ... except in this one situation:

If the user scrolls to the last item in the list, then touches it, that item expands in place and out of view.  In other words, as the item expands, it extends the bottom of the list, but the list does not auto scroll to keep all of the expanded item "on screen" or "in view" within the bounds of the RecyclerView.

I have tried to RecyclerView.scrollToPosition() to the last position in the list, but the list doesn't move.

The user *can* manually scroll the list and bring the full expanded item into view, but I want it to happen automatically.

Thoughts?

Edit: I don't know if this is influencing things, or not, but the list is already manually scrolled to the bottom of the list so it seems like it would be redundant to programmaticaly scroll to the same position.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is 'refresh' the scroll position in the list to bring the entire final list entry into view.

Comment: I have also tried to use the LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition() method but I get the same result.

Comment: I solved like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51610374/408780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was *almost* there with the use of the LinearLayoutManager scroll method.  The solution, for me, was to use `LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset()` while providing the extra size of the expanded view as the offset.

```
int distanceInPixels;
View firstVisibleChild = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
int itemHeight = firstVisibleChild.getHeight();
int currentPosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(firstVisibleChild);
int p = Math.abs(position - currentPosition);
if (p > 5) distanceInPixels = (p - (p - 5)) * itemHeight;
else       distanceInPixels = p * itemHeight;
layoutMgr.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, distanceInPixels);
```

Comment: Hi,can you please share an example. I've wasted 6-7 hrs on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "max_size - 1" as the position argument inside the `recyclerView.scrollToPosition()` method. Here, max_size is the count of items in your list.

Comment: As I said in the original post, I've tried to scroll to the last position in the list i.e. .scrollToPosition(max_size - 1).  Incidentally, I've also tried to scroll one index past the end of the list i.e. .scrollToPosition(max_size) using your terms.

Comment: It actually works for me. Apparently you cannot excess the scroll to go behond the real limits of the adapter... Thanks!